# MIME database file on Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019, mime

I'm working with IIS 10, on a Windows Server 2019 and I'm trying to export the MIME database to another WS-2019.

Is there any path where the database is stored? I can't find anything similar in Windows.

Any help is Welcome

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS, server wide MIME types are stored on applicationHost.config file, found on C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config.

Site specific MIME types are stored on web.config file, in the root folder of your site.
In either case, look at

```
<configuration><system.webServer><staticContent>
```

inside you'll found something lile

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".323" mimeType="text/h323" />
```

There's not a real database, all is stored in these XML files.

Comment: Thank you very much @Massimo, that's was very helpful for me!